# How to skew div layout with CSS, and allow image to fill skewed area

Tags: html, css

Hope you can help as I've been struggling with this one all day.

Our designer has come up with a design that has the panels across the page skewed, with text on one side and image on the other.

However, he wants the image on the right to fill the area that looks like it goes under the left, so that the left panel at the top appears to overlap the image.

An example for you:

[image]

HTML is pretty basic at this stage:

```
<div class="rr rr-left">
    <div>
        <h2>ABOUT</h2>
        <p>Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rr rr-right">
</div>
```

And here is the CSS Ive been using from another example on here:

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
}


h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.rr > div {
  text-align: left;
}

.rr {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  background: #004B5F;
}
.rr.rr-left {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 54%;
}
.rr.rr-right {
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  width: 45.5%;
  background-image: url('../img/animage.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color: #004B5F;
}

.rr:after,
.rr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rr-left:after {
  right: 0px;
  border-left: 100px solid #004B5F;
  border-bottom: 400px solid #ffffff;
}

.rr-right:before {
  left: -100px;
  border-right: 100px solid #004B5F;
  border-top: 400px solid transparent;
}

.rr-left > div {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.rr-right > div {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution

```
<div class="rr rr-left">
    <div>
        <h2>ABOUT</h2>
        <p>Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rr rr-right">
</div>

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
}


h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.rr > div {
  text-align: left;
}

.rr {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  background: #004B5F;
}
.rr.rr-left {
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  width: 44%;
}
.rr.rr-right {
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  width: 56%;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/550x550');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-color: #004B5F;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rr:after,
.rr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.rr-right:after {
  height: 120%;
  width: 100px;
  background: #004B5F;
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  left: -68px;
  top: -20px;
  }

.rr-left > div {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.rr-right > div {
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/mv1d9a9a/2/

Comment: BOOM! Thats it @grinmax So it was the transform and the left/top that was the key? Making I sure I understand what you did.

Answer (score 0):

for wrapper div image `transform: skewX(-20deg)`
for img inside wrapper `transform: skewX(20deg)`

Comment: Thanks @Artur-moroz, will the image appear like the left panel overlaps it at the top with no blue background in the bottom left of the right panel?

Comment: Im actually needing the image to stay straight on and appear to fill the available area, rather than skew the image (if I think that is what that is doing?)

Answer (score 0):

Add html like this:

```
 <div class="rr-container">
        <div class="rr rr-left">
            <div class="rr-content">
                <h2>ABOUT</h2>
                <p>Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum Lorum ipsum </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rr rr-right">
        </div>
```

Add style like this:

```
    body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
      padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.rr-container{    background: #607D8B;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;}
.rr-left {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
    background: #607D8B;    
    border-right: 20px solid #607D8B;    
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
.rr-right {
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    color: #2E8DEF;
    background: #333333;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2E8DEF;
}
.rr-content{
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(30deg, 0deg);
}
```